# Connect a Heading with Subheadings

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am currently working on the following excel sheet:
[this is the excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpzZy.png)

I am quite new to Excel and I just found out about the VBA function. Do you guys think that it is possible to write a code that does essentially the following:

If [Total Debt Stock] -> select the next 6 cells below and add to these cells "TDS" at the beginning.

And follwing this: If [short-term debt] -> select the next 2 (for instance) cells below and add "STD".

The aim is to copy the following pdf and also keep the "embeddedness" structure of the pdf (i.e. Albania-Total Debt-Short Term Debt- Official creditior) so that STATA can use that easily [this is the pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGyM2.png)

Has anyone ever done something like this?

Thanks in advance!

All the best,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then I think you can use the following:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lLoop As Long
    
    For lRow = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If InStr(1, LCase(Cells(lRow, 1)), "total debt stock") > 0 Then
            For lLoop = 1 To 6
                Cells(lRow + lLoop, 1) = "TDS-" & Cells(lRow + lLoop, 1)
            Next lLoop
            lRow = lRow + 6
        End If
        
        If InStr(1, LCase(Cells(lRow, 1)), "short-term debt") > 0 Then
            For lLoop = 1 To 2
                Cells(lRow + lLoop, 1) = "STD-" & Cells(lRow + lLoop, 1)
            Next lLoop
            lRow = lRow + 2
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

For testing if a cell "contains" either Total Debt Stock or Short-term debt, I change everything to lowercase, so you might want to change that. I also added a hyphen after "TDS" and "STD".

Comment: Hey Dave, 
Thanks a lot for your great answer; highly appreciated. Ill try that and see whether it works.
All the best,
Greg

Comment: not sure why, but it keeps on returning "invalid outside procedure". Any idea how I can resolve that?

Comment: Hi @gregthenovelist, I edited the routine by placing it in a Sub; hopefully, that will solve the problem. If not, let me know which line is throwing the error.